# What is responsible for triggering a Hibernate's SchemaExport.execute (hbm2ddl.auto) during a JUnit/Spring test?

Tags: spring-test

What is the Spring event responsible for triggering a Hibernate's `SchemaExport.execute` (considering that `hbm2ddl.auto` is activated) during a JUnit/Spring test run with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`?

(All of this bearing in mind I can have several test suites with the same context configuration and that the spring contexts can be cached...)

I ask this question because I have set up a Spring listener (used as a data populator) as follows:

```
@Profile({ Profiles.DEFAULT, Profiles.CLOUD, Profiles.TEST, Profiles.DEV })
@Component
public class BootstrapLoaderListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>, ResourceLoaderAware, Ordered {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BootstrapLoaderListener.class);

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        initApplication();
    }
    ...
```

And I have a two integration test suites (`SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`) that share the same context configuration and therefore the same cached application context.

But I noticed that when the second of the two test suites runs **after** the first one, the above application listener is not notified.

So to sum up:

- the first test suite runs (with create tables from schema export **and** with application listener being notified)
- the second test suite runs (with only create tables **but without** the application listener being notified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javadoc for `ContextRefreshedEvent` clearly states that it is an...

> Event raised when an `ApplicationContext` gets initialized or refreshed.

Thus your `BootstrapLoaderListener` will only get invoked when the `ApplicationContext` starts (i.e., gets initialized or refreshed), which only happens once: when the Spring TestContext Framework loads the context for your test. Though, if you are using `@DirtiesContext`, your `ApplicationContext` may get recreated multiple times.

In other words, the behavior you are witnessing regarding your listener is by design and to be expected.

As for why your schema would be created a second time, that remains a mystery. Typically this should not happen. For example, if you are using Spring's `LocalSessionFactoryBean` or `LocalSessionFactoryBuilder`, each of these factories will create a Hibernate `SessionFactory` only once, when the `ApplicationContext` is initialized or refreshed.

Perhaps you have some non-standard configuration that causes the `SessionFactory` to be created more than once, but I cannot judge that based on the information you have supplied.

However, using an `ApplicationListener` to set up a test database is not advisable if you want the setup code to be invoked before each test (simply because it will not be invoked multiple times automatically). If you really want to use an `ApplicationListener` in tests, you could fire your own `ContextRefreshedEvent` in the `ApplicationContext` for your test from within an `@Before` or `@BeforeTransaction` method.

As an alternative (and likely better solution), you can programmatically invoke SQL scripts within an `@Before` or `@BeforeTransaction` method via one of the following:

- one of the `SimpleJdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript(...)` methods (on Spring 2.5 - 3.x)
- one of the `JdbcTestUtils.executeSqlScript(...)` methods (on Spring 4.x and higher)
- one of the `ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(...)` methods (on Spring 4.0.3 and higher)
- the `executeSqlScript(...)` method in `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` or `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests`
- a `ResourceDatabasePopulator` and `DatabasePopulatorUtils`

And as of the yet-to-be-released Spring 4.1, you can declaratively invoke SQL scripts via the `@Sql` annotation.

Good luck!

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

p.s. you could also implement a custom `TestExecutionListener` to programmatically invoke SQL scripts using the same options mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam for this detailed reply. Regarding the `ContextRefreshedEvent`, it is actually as I thought. Now about the schema being recreated a second time, it is still a mystery to me too! I will definitely comment here when I do find the cause of the problem.